# Can you have a TCP client without threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

Normally I wouldn't want to try this but I am making a custom unity server and unity is having problems with multithreading and does not allow you to use any unity functionality and says this must be called from the main thread. So my question is, is it possible to make a TCP client receive without threading. I have looked around and I have not been able to find an alternative.

The code that I have at the moment:

```
//TCP
TCP = new TcpClient (ip, 25001);
stream = TCP.GetStream ();

//TCP thread
TCPrecieve = new Thread (new ThreadStart (TCPRecieve));
TCPrecieve.IsBackground = true;
TCPrecieve.Start ();



public void TCPRecieve () {
        IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, ((IPEndPoint)TCP.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port);
        StreamReader TCPReader = new StreamReader (stream);
        string data = "";

        while ((data = TCPReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            AnalyseTCP (data);
        }
    }
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use the `Begin...` functions from the TcpClient class if you don't want the client to block.

Comment: Yeah, async programming ftw, Matthew.

Comment: You can but you need to have some kind of a primary wait point that wakes up whenever you have data on the socket, or whenever you have to do some other kind of work. It can be achieved using select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have can be made to not use threads trivially: Simply delete the thread and run `TCPRecieve` inline. I doubt that is what you want, though. In fact you probably want the connect operation to also not happen on the main thread so that it is not blocked.

Having multiple threads is not a problem. The problem comes when you access unity objects from disallowed threads. Don't do that. You can run the TCP work on a background thread.

I don't know much about unity but you need to [marshal calls to the main thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/305882/how-do-i-invoke-functions-on-the-main-thread.html).

Using async IO does *not* solve this problem because completion callbacks are invoked on thread-pool threads.